# Show a subset of $\mathbb{C}[0,1]$ closed under uniform topology

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I encountered a set $L_{\leq k}$(will be defined below) as a subset of $\mathbb{C}[0,1]$, and I want to determine if this set is closed or not. Here $\mathbb{C}[0,1]$ is the set of continuous functions with domain $[0,1]$, and I will restrict the discussion of closeness with respect to the uniform topology.

Consider non-decreasing paths in $\mathbb{C}[0,1]$ such that when the path increases, it will increase with rate 1. So you could imagine such path as increasing with rate 1 and staying flat alternatively on a sequence of subintervals of [0,1]. $L_{\leq k}$ is the set of such paths such that the number of flat intervals is smaller or equal to $k$. Here $k$ is a given fixed integer.

I think the set $L_{\leq k}$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is closed w.r.t the uniform topology, i.e. if $x_n\in L_{\leq k}$, and $||x_n-x||\rightarrow 0$, then $x\in L_{\leq k}$ as well.

Could anyone provide a quick proof of this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L_m$ denote the set of functions with exactly $m$ flat segments. Then $L_{\le k}=\bigcup_{m=0}^k.$ Consider    a Cauchy sequence  $x_n$ in $L_{\le k}.$ There exists $m$ such that $L_m$ contains infinitely many terms $x_n.$ With no loss of generality we may assume that $x_n\in L_m.$ For $x_n$ let $[a_{j,n},b_{j,n}],$ $1\le j\le m,$ denote consecutive subintervals of $[0,1]$ corresponding to the flat segments of the graph. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem there is a subsequence $n_i$ such that all sequences $a_{j,n_i}$ and $b_{j,n_i},$ $j=1,2,\ldots, m,$ are convergent. Again with no loss of generality we may assume that $a_{j,n}$ and $b_{j,n}$ are convergent. Denote $a_j=\lim_na_{j,n}$ and $b_j=\lim_nb_{j,n}.$ The sequence $x_n$ is therefore pointwise convergent to a function $x$ such that $x$ is constant on $[a_j,b_j],$ $j=1,2,\ldots, m,$  and growing at the rate $1$ on the remaining segments. The number of flat segments of $x$ is less  or equal $m.$ This number will be less than $m$, if $b_j=a_{j+1}$ for some $j.$